# How do I control the log level for Azure Diagnostic Logs?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have built a ASPNET Core application and enabled logs with these statements:

```
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug((category, logLevel) => (category.Contains("WEBAPI") && logLevel >= LogLevel.Trace));
    loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

Now the problem is that the Azure log has lots of other log detail coming from the Mircosoft packages that I am not interested in. I can't seem to pass my logging configuration to Azure though like I do for the Console log.

Am I missing how I should be using the Diagnostics system?

Comment: What is the log detail set to in the portal? You should be able to set the level there to e.g. Warning.

Comment: @juunas It's set to Verbose, what I meant to ask is how do I control the level BY category. That's what I can't figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable application diagnostics in **Azure portal**, you also could choose the Level. This setting allows you to filter the information captured to informational, warning or error information.

[image]

The Verbose level means the log system will log all information produced by the application.

> Now the problem is that the Azure log has lots of other log detail coming from the Mircosoft packages that I am not interested in.

You could change the level on Azure portal to filter the logs which you want to save. You could change the level on Azure portal at any time you want. Unlike changing the web.config file, changing diagnostic log levels will not recycle the app domain that the application runs within.

> I want to exclude logs from categories that aren't mine, just line I do on the first line in my question with the config.

Azure Web App Logging extension doesn't support filter logs by category. You could create a new logger provide to implement this feature.

There are 3 steps to finish it.

**Step 1** : Add a CustomLogger class which need to implement ILogger interface. In this class, we could filter logs by level and category and save log message to any place we wanted.

```
public class CustomLogger : ILogger
{

    private string _categoryName;

    private Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;

    public CustomLogger(string categoryName, Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter)
    {
        _categoryName = categoryName;
        _filter = filter;
    }


    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return (_filter == null || _filter(_categoryName, logLevel));
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {

        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (formatter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formatter));
        }

        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            return;
        }

        message = $@"Level: {logLevel} {message}";

        if (exception != null)
        {
            message += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + exception.ToString();
        }

        //save message to any place you wanted
    }
}
```

**Step 2** : Add a CustomLoggerProvider class which need to implement ILoggerProvider interface. In this class, we will create a instance of CustomerLogger to log information.

```
public class CustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly Func<string, LogLevel, bool> _filter;

    public CustomLoggerProvider(Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter)
    {
        _filter = filter;
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return new CustomLogger(categoryName, _filter);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

**Step 3** : Add CustomLoggerExtensions class which is used to add CustomLoggerProvider instance to logger factory.

```
public static class CustomLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggerFactory AddCustom(this ILoggerFactory factory,
                                          Func<string, LogLevel, bool> filter = null)
    {
        factory.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider(filter));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

After upper steps, we could use this custom logger using following code.

```
loggerFactory.AddCustom((category, logLevel) => (category.Contains("WEBAPI") && logLevel >= LogLevel.Trace));
```

Comment: This is great information! But what I really meant is I want to filter based on category... I want to exclude logs from categories that aren't mine, just line I do on the first line in my question with the config.

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding your question. I updated my reply based on your comment.

Comment: Wow! Now that's an answer! Thanks SO much.